# Macular Microcurrent Therapy update (literature search)

Tags: search, us7187977

In reference to the patent: [WO 2003/105945 A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2003105945A2) ([US 7,187,977 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7187977))

This study was reported twelve years ago and appears to have helped three patients by microcurrent therapy.

Where can I find follow up data and newer studies concerning the efficacy of this therapy?

Comment: If you look at the [forward citations](https://www.google.com/patents/US7187977#forward-citations) for the patent, you will find several newer patent applications that reference the grant. Follow each of those links to the newer applications (for instance, [WO 2012/021583 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012021583A1), then follow to the US patent grant or application (e.g., [US 9,037,248 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US9037248)) and navigate to the [non-patent citations](https://www.google.com/patents/US9037248?cl=en#npl-citations). You'll likely find dozens of newer references.